# Spark Dataframes- Reducing By Key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Let's say I have a data structure like this where ts is some timestamp

```
case class Record(ts: Long, id: Int, value: Int)
```

Given a large number of these records I want to end up with the record with the highest timestamp for each id.  Using the RDD api I think the following code gets the job done:

```
def findLatest(records: RDD[Record])(implicit spark: SparkSession) = {
  records.keyBy(_.id).reduceByKey{
    (x, y) => if(x.ts > y.ts) x else y
  }.values
}
```

Likewise this is my attempt with datasets:

```
def findLatest(records: Dataset[Record])(implicit spark: SparkSession) = {
  records.groupByKey(_.id).mapGroups{
    case(id, records) => {
      records.reduceLeft((x,y) => if (x.ts > y.ts) x else y)
    }
  }
}
```

I've being trying to work out how to achieve something similar with dataframes but to no avail- I realise I can do the grouping with:

```
records.groupBy($"id")
```

But that gives me a RelationGroupedDataSet and it's not clear to me what aggregation function I need to write to achieve what I want- all example aggregations I've seen appear to focus on returning just a single column being aggregated rather than the whole row.

Is it possible to achieve this using dataframes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the argmax logic (see [databricks example](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1023043053387187/3170497669323442/2840265927289860/latest.html))

For example, lets say your dataframe is called df and it has the columns id, val, ts you would do something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newDF = df.groupBy('id).agg.max(struct('ts, 'val)) as 'tmp).select($"id", $"tmp.*")
```

Comment: yup that works perfectly, thank you! as aside I think you have a slight typo in the answer- the period after agg should be a parenthesis!

Comment: Can you explain why this works? Is the max applied only on the first column?

Comment: @user238607 max uses the ordering for the column. The implicit ordering for a struct (or tuple) is by the ordering of the first element.

Comment: works fine, jus agree with TS, there is a typo - there should be ( between agg & max

Answer (score 0):

For Datasets I did this,tested on Spark 2.1.1

```
final case class AggregateResultModel(id: String,
                                      mtype: String,
                                      healthScore: Int,
                                      mortality: Float,
                                      reimbursement: Float)
.....
.....

// assume that the rawScores are loaded behorehand from json,csv files

val groupedResultSet = rawScores.as[AggregateResultModel].groupByKey( item => (item.id,item.mtype ))
      .reduceGroups( (x,y) => getMinHealthScore(x,y)).map(_._2)


// the binary function used in the reduceGroups

def getMinHealthScore(x : AggregateResultModel, y : AggregateResultModel): AggregateResultModel = {
    // complex logic for deciding between which row to keep
    if (x.healthScore > y.healthScore) { return y }
    else if (x.healthScore < y.healthScore) { return x }
    else {

      if (x.mortality < y.mortality) { return y }
      else if (x.mortality > y.mortality) { return x }
      else  {

        if(x.reimbursement < y.reimbursement)
          return x
        else
          return y

      }

    }

  }
```