# how to select elements in scala dataframe?

Tags: scala, dataframe

Reference to [How do I select item with most count in a dataframe and define is as a variable in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136971/how-do-i-select-item-with-most-count-in-a-dataframe-and-define-is-as-a-variable)

Given a table below, how can I select nth src_ip and put it as a variable?

```
+--------------+------------+
|        src_ip|src_ip_count|
+--------------+------------+
|  58.242.83.11|          52|
|58.218.198.160|          33|
|58.218.198.175|          22|
|221.194.47.221|           6|
```

Comment: please post your desired data set

Comment: You want to get the nth in terms of src_ip_count? does it have to be exact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another *column* with *row number* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val tempdf = df.withColumn("row_number", monotonically_increasing_id())
tempdf.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("row_number")))
```

which should give you `tempdf` as

```
+--------------+------------+----------+
|        src_ip|src_ip_count|row_number|
+--------------+------------+----------+
|  58.242.83.11|          52|         1|
|58.218.198.160|          33|         2|
|58.218.198.175|          22|         3|
|221.194.47.221|           6|         4|
+--------------+------------+----------+
```

Now you can use `filter` to *filter* in the nth `row` as

```
  .filter($"row_number" === n)
```

That should be it.

For extracting the ip, lets say your n is 2 as

```
val n = 2
```

Then the above process would give you

```
+--------------+------------+----------+
|        src_ip|src_ip_count|row_number|
+--------------+------------+----------+
|58.218.198.160|          33|         2|
+--------*------+------------+----------+
```

getting the ip address* is explained in the link you provided in the question by doing

```
.head.get(0)
```

Safest way is to use `zipWithIndex` in the `dataframe` converted into `rdd` and then convert back to `dataframe`, so that we have unmistakable `row_number` column.

```
val finalDF = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(row => (row._1(0).toString, row._1(1).toString, (row._2+1).toInt)).toDF("src_ip", "src_ip_count", "row_number")
```

Rest of the steps are already explained before.

Comment: Ramesh Maharjan, my understanding of `monotonically_increasing_id()` is that it guarantees only generating `Long`s in a monotonically increasing fashion, but not necessarily consecutive integers starting from 0.

Comment: Yes @LeoC, You are absolutely correct. Please see my updated answer. Thanks for the feedback. Please do comment if you still see drawbacks.

Comment: is there a ways to put the element out from dataframe by indexing of dataframe?

Comment: @user3782604 isn't that explained in the link you provided in your question? `val element = df.head.get(0)` is the way to save it in a variable. I and the link both have explained them.